# Is "ye" in the singular used with singular or plural verb conjugations?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, archaicisms, early-modern-english, conjugation

I was writing some dialogue for a story and I wanted a character from the past to speak in an archaic/Early Modern English way, when I stumbled across this.

In this instance, I'm using "ye" in the singular as a formal/polite term of address, but am unsure of the verb that follows. At first, I used "art", as it's the second person singular conjugation, but then I remembered that "they" in the singular still uses plural conjugations ("they are" not "they is"), so now I'm confused as to which one I should use.

At the moment I'm leaning toward plural conjugations: **"ye are"**, not **"ye art"**.

I found only one mention of this online, on Quora where someone asked this exact thing, but all the answers talked about using ye in the plural, and I wanted to find out if being used in the singular would change it.

Which one, if any, would be correct?

Comment: If the plural form is used for politeness (as it still is in a number of languages), the verb has to be plural as well.

Comment: Are you making up this use of ye? Where did you find it described or used?

Comment: @StuartF No: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/ye_pron?tab=meaning_and_use#13732377) (definition I.3.a.), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English#Pronouns) (specifically the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Early_Modern_English_personal_pronouns_(table%29)), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ye#Pronoun).

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks!

Comment: It's analogous to the way we use plural verbs with the singular "they".